# For polynomials $f(x), p(x)$ in a polynomial ring $K[X]$, $K$ a field, where $p(x)|f(x)$ does it then imply that $\frac{f(x)}{p(x)} \in K[X]$ aswel?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field, splitting-field

I'm doing a problem about extension fields $K \subset L$,  $L$ being algebraic and have that deg(Irr$(\alpha, K)$) = 2 for an $\alpha \in L$. This means Irr$(\alpha, K) = (X-\alpha)(X-\beta)$ for some $\beta$. My idea was that $(X-\beta) = \frac{\text{Irr}(\alpha, K)}{X-\alpha} \in L[X]$ $\Rightarrow$ $\beta \in L$ but i'm suddenly not sure about the fact about the polynomials. It seems true obviously, but is this true?

Comment: How do you define $p(x) \mid f(x)$?

Comment: $\exists q(x)\in K[X|$ st. $q(x)p(x) = f(x)$ got it, thanks! :D

Comment: $p(x)|f(x) \Leftrightarrow$ there is a $f'(x) \in K[X]$ such that $p(x)f'(x)=f(x)$